# Proxy settings in TortoiseSVN and command line svn client

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

It seems to me that if I enable proxy server in TortoiseSVN then pure command line svn client also starts work via proxy server.
Is it correct?
If yes - where TortoiseSVN stores this setting?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The settings are store here, depending on your OS:

**The server file is created when you install TortoiseSVN, Eclipse or command-line Subversion. Use the appropriate path from the installation folder to configure proxy settings:**

- **CLI Unix/Linux** :  /home/username/.subversion/servers
- **CLI Windows (2k, XP)**: C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Subversion\servers
- **CLI Windows (Vista/7)**: C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers
- **Eclipse**:  Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections
- **IE (6/7)**:     Tools > Options > Advanced Network > Connection Settings
- **Firefox**:  Tools > Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN Settings
- **TortoiseSVN**:  Windows Explorer > File > TortoiseSVN > Settings > Network (by default, TSVN uses system proxy settings)